# How to overwrite specific page of PDF with another page of another PDF with Python's PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I want to overwrite the first page of a PDF with another page of another PDF using the [PyPDF2 library](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) in Python.

For more detail, I have two separate PDFs (let's call them `overwritten.pdf` and `other.pdf`) and I want to replace the first (it doesn't have to be the first) page of `overwritten.pdf` with a specific page of `other.pdf` so the first page of `overwritten.pdf` is that specific page of `other.pdf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can literally "replace a page" with PyPDF2. I would use the [merge function](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/merging-pdfs.html). Example from the PyPDF2 web site:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

merger = PdfMerger()

input1 = open("document1.pdf", "rb")
input2 = open("document2.pdf", "rb")
input3 = open("document3.pdf", "rb")

# add the first 3 pages of input1 document to output
merger.append(fileobj=input1, pages=(0, 3))

# insert the first page of input2 into the output beginning after the second page
merger.merge(position=2, fileobj=input2, pages=(0, 1))

# append entire input3 document to the end of the output document
merger.append(input3)

# Write to an output PDF document
output = open("document-output.pdf", "wb")
merger.write(output)

# Close File Descriptors
merger.close()
output.close()
```